# How to return to a hyperlink(the CTRL+CLICK link) on word for mac with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

The alternative for this on word for windows is ALT + LeftArrow.I would like to know what the mac equivalent is?
I found an answer here https://superuser.com/a/746208/1097561

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This is an interesting question, but most likely you will get a better answer on Ask Different, the Stack Exchange Site for Apple products.

Comment: You might also get a quicker answer on Microsoft Answers. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_OfH-mso_OPMac If you cross-post,, please follow common cross-posting etiquette. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_OfH-mso_OPMac?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1

Comment: Please define what "return to a hyperlink" means in Word.  I have Word for both, and would answer if I knew what this meant on either platform.  Consider using a picture of this in Word for Windows too.

Comment: Thank you I will ask in the Microsoft Mac forums. P.s what is cross posting?